# Block call of method in TypeScript if caller is not allowed

Tags: typescript

I have created a decorator that looks for the name of the caller of a method, and matches with a list of "allowed" callers

My objective is to maintain the method implementation in only one place

So I want to know, it's correct to make something like this? I haven't tried in production yet, it will cause an issue? It's possible to improve it, if so, how?

Thanks!

The code or [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-decorator-protectmethod):

```js
function protectMethod(allowedCaller: string[]) {
  return function(target, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function(...args: any[]) {
      /**
       * callerName by Iris Li
       * https://gist.github.com/irisli/716b6dacd3f151ce2b7e
       */
      var stackTrace = new Error().stack; // Only tested in latest FF and Chrome
      var callerName = stackTrace.replace(/^Error\s+/, ""); // Sanitize Chrome
      callerName = callerName.split("\n")[1].trim(); // 1st item is this, 2nd item is caller
      callerName = callerName.replace(/^\s+at Object./, ""); // Sanitize Chrome
      callerName = callerName.replace(/ \(.+\)$/, ""); // Sanitize Chrome
      if (callerName.slice(0, 3) == "at ") callerName = callerName.slice(3); // Sanitize Chrome
      callerName = callerName.replace(/\@.+/, ""); // Sanitize Firefox

      const allowed = allowedCaller.filter(e => {
        return e === callerName;
      });
      if (!allowed.length) {
        console.warn(`Caller "${callerName}" should not call "${propertyKey}"`);
      }

      originalMethod.apply(this, args);
    };
  };
}

class Class1 {
  search: Class2 = new Class2()
  call_method() {
    this.search.method_service(true);
  }
}

class Class2 {
  constructor() {}

  @protectMethod(["Class1.call_method"])
  method_service(v) {
    console.log("service called ", v);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[stack property is not standard and should not be used in production](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Stack)

Sorry, I don't have an alternative method.